# Disable SSH remote tunneling

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables, ssh-tunnel, forwarding

I need to restrict SSH tunnel functions. Users should not be allowed to create remote tunnels but only tunnels to localhost. I tried to setup the whole thing in the SSH configuration but I can only turn off the TCPForwarding completely there. I guess this might only be possible with iptables then? Does anyone have experience and can help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For OpenSSH you can use `PermitOpen host:port` to limit where users can tunnel to. To let them tunnel to MySQL that only listens locally on the default port:

```
PermitOpen LocalHost:3306
```

From the man page for sshd_config:

> **PermitOpen**
>
> Specifies the destinations to which TCP port forwarding is permitted.
>   The forwarding specification must be one of the following forms:
>
> ```
> PermitOpen host:port
> PermitOpen IPv4_addr:port
> PermitOpen [IPv6_addr]:port
> ```
>
> Multiple forwards may be specified by separating them with white space.
>   An argument of *any* can be used to remove all restrictions and permit
>   any forwarding requests.  An argument of *none* can be used to prohibit
>   all forwarding requests.  By default all port forwarding requests are
>   permitted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works with localhost:<PORT> but not with "any". It seems like every single port needs to be inserted at this point.

Comment: Correct. Still usually not that many local ports users would want to connect to anyway.

Comment: That's right but it's might be worth a feature request ;-)

Comment: @Brian Try using `PermitOpen localhost:*`

Comment: @kurtm this gives the error "bad port number in PermitOpen"

Comment: @VladislavDzabantov Weird.  I ran that config through sshd -t on a server.  Running through -T it turned it into `permitopen localhost:0`.  So I'd suggest trying that next.

Comment: @kurtm Same error when I use localhost:0 - I am using version 1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1.1

Comment: @VladislavDzabantov Yeah, I'm using OpenSSH 6.2.  The good news is it seems they *have* added that functionality to future versions :)

Comment: @kurtm Okay then I need to upgrade that package manually. I also found this: https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1513#c3. He is pointing out that you can use :* and :1-1000.